# bar chart and yerrorlines together in a single plot

Tags: gnuplot, confidence-interval

I have question regarding bar chart and yerrorlines. How can I plot them together? I want to plot a graph like this:

[image]

But, I'm unable to get that.

```
x  Scheme#1 Scheme#2 Scheme#3 Minfor#1 Mxfor#1 Minfor#2 Mxfor#2 Minfor#3 Mxfor#1
20  0.0351  0.04562  0.04777  0.0208   0.0385  0.0415   0.0526  0.0397   0.05601  
40 0.03279  0.03946 0.034171  0.0266   0.0393  0.0323   0.04662 0.0278   0.04055
60 0.03367 0.033792 0.037776  0.0272   0.0401  0.02692  0.04066 0.029    0.04584
```

**Plot function**

```
plot "data.file" using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Scheme 1', \
     "data.file" using 3 title ' Scheme 2', \
     "data.file" using 4 title ' Scheme 3',\
     "data.file" using 0:2:5:6 title 'Confidence Interval for Scheme 1' with yerrorlines,\
     "data.file" using 0:3:7:8 title 'Confidence Interval for Scheme 2' with yerrorlines,\
     "data.file" using 0:4:9:10 title 'Confidence Interval for Scheme 3' with yerrorlines
```

column 5 and 6 contains values of **Confidence Interval** for the data in col 2. 
column 7 and 8 contains values of **Confidence Interval** for the data in col 3. 
column 9 and 10 contains values of **Confidence Interval** for the data in col 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "witherrorbars.png"

set yrange [0:]

set bars 2

set style data histogram
set style histogram errorbars gap 1 lw 1
set style fill solid border -1

plot "data.file" using 2:5:6:xtic(1) title 'Scheme 1' lc 5, \
     "data.file" using 3:7:8         title 'Scheme 2' lc 7, \
     "data.file" using 4:9:10        title 'Scheme 3' lc 9
```

The interesting line is `set style histogram errorbars` which combines the boxes and the errorbars. This is the result with gnuplot 4.6:

[image: boxes with errorbars]

The colors `lc 5`, `lc 7`, and `lc 9` are chosen randomly, so adjust them to your needs. The line `set bars 2` enlarges the tics at the end of the bars.